# Retry vue resource ajax calls using recursion

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js, vue-resource

I'm trying to have my ajax call retry if it fails initially. It does it 3 times each time if the initial ajax call fails with a timeout of 5 seconds. The function is being imported on my vue component as a method and being called on `ready()`

```
export function getOrderStatus (order) {
  let url = `/orders/status/${order.id}`
  let promise = this.$http.get(url)

  function retry(order, path, promise, retryAttempt) {
    promise.then((response) => {
      if (response.body.status === 'success') {
        showOrderStatus()
      }
    }, (response) => {
      if (retries < 2) {
        retryAttempt++
        setTimeout(retry(order, path, promise, retryAttempt), 5000);
      } else {
        handleError()
      }
    })
  }

  retry(order, path, promise, 0)
}
```

Component

```
  import { getOrderStatus } from '../shared'

  export default {
   name: 'order-page',
   props: { order },
   methods: { getOrderStatus },
   ready() {
     this.getOrderStatus(order)
   }
 }
```

I'm not sure if this is the best way to go about retrying ajax calls so any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to refactor this because you are caching `promise`. The issue here is that Promises by nature will only complete once, resolving or rejecting. Therefore if your $http request does fail, your future calls to `retry()` will all also fail without calling the endpoint.

Try something like below:

**component** could be refactored to a mixin if you want to share it across components (rather than `import { getOrderStatus } from '../shared'`)

```
data () {
    return {
        attempt: 0,
    }
}

methods: {

    showOrder () { // or whatever needs this

        this.getOrderStatus('order-123')
            .then((reponse) => this.showOrderStatus())
            .catch((reponse) => this.handleError(response))

    },

    getOrderStatus (order) {

        this.attempt = 0

        return 
            new Promise((resolve, reject) => this.callOrderEndpoint({
                order,
                resolve,
                reject,
            }))

    },

    callOrderEndpoint ({ order, resolve, reject }) {

        const url = `/orders/status/${order.id}`

        this.$http
            .get(url)
            .then((response) => {
                if (response.body.status === 'success') {
                    resolve()
                } else {
                    reject()
                }
            })
            .catch(response) => {
                if (this.attempt++ < 2) {
                    setTimeout(() => 
                        this.callOrderEndpoint({ order, resolve, reject }), 
                        5000))
                } else {
                    reject(response)
                }
            })

    },

    showOrderStatus () {

        // whatever this does

    },

    handleError (response) {

        console.error('fail')

    },

},
```

I thought a better way to go would be to return a Promise from `getOrderStatus`. This would allow you to move your success / fail methods to the then / catch methods for better structure.

Comment: thanks I think this is coming together more. Any idea why i'm getting `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: reject is not a function` though?

Comment: I can only assume either I made a typo above or when copying to your code something went amiss. I'd just log the various methods and see where it's going wrong.If i get a chance I'll see if I can build a demo later...

Comment: thanks I resolved it actually. One more question though, where should showOrder() be called? I'm assuming that replaces my original `ready()` function

Comment: Exactly, you'd call that whenever you needed